# how return args works in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm new to Java8

Can anyone share what `return args` is returning in below code snippet ? How it looks like in Java 7 to understand what's actually happening ?

```
public ApplicationRunner initializeConnection(
        RsvpsWebSocketHandler rsvpsWebSocketHandler) {
           return args -> {
               WebSocketClient rsvpsSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

               rsvpsSocketClient.doHandshake(
                   rsvpsWebSocketHandler, MEETUP_RSVPS_ENDPOINT);           
           };
       }
```

Comment: Do you know what a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) is?

Comment: @Abra OP mentioned being new to Java 8. Most probably OP doesn't know what the `lambda` is.

Comment: You have to read the entire statement, from the `return` to the corresponding `;`. The statement is not `return args` but `return args -> { … };`.

Comment: @Holger, How it justifies that "return args -> { … };" is an implementation of ApplicationRunner's run method ? And secondly, Does "return args" returns instance of anonymous class implementing ApplicationRunner ?

Comment: `args -> { … }` will evaluate to an instance of `ApplicationRunner`. But why don’t you follow the link [given by Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399826/how-return-args-works-in-java-8?noredirect=1#comment112108931_63399826) and read?

Answer (score 2):

It's a `lambda`, which is just a shorthand initialization of an anonymous class.
In `Java 1.7` it would look like:

```
return new ApplicationRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
                WebSocketClient rsvpsSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

                rsvpsSocketClient.doHandshake(rsvpsWebSocketHandler, MEETUP_RSVPS_ENDPOINT);
            }
        };
```

Comment: then in 1.8 version, where is "ApplicationArguments args" being passed ?

Comment: Since `run` is the only method of `ApplicationRunner`, you can instantiate anonymous class by simply defining that method. The `lambda` syntax assumes that all of the method arguments are on the left side of `->`token. For more details please read [the official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).